# XPath for selecting a node under a specific node with zero or more nodes in between

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing, xpathnavigator

My Xml looks something like this

```
      <root>
       <parent name="Iam">
          <child1 name="123">
              <toy name="wii">
              </toy>
          </child>
       </parent>
       <parent name="Iam">
          <toy name="wii">
          </toy>
       </parent>
       <parent name="Sam">
          <child1 name="999">
             <toy name="xbox">
             </toy>
           </child>
        </parent>
      </root>
```

I need to select all <toy> nodes with name="wii" under <parent> with name="Iam". Notice that <toy> can be direct child of <parent>or a grandchild of <parent>(under <child>)

<child>node can have 0 or more cardinality.

I tried using this xpath **/parent[@name='Iam']/*/toy[@name='wii']** with XPathNavigator.

```
`XPathNodeIterator nodeIter = schemaNavigator.Select(schemaXPath, namespaceMgr);`
```

It is obviously wrong since it fails.

I need xpath for selecting all nodes between <parent> and <toy> with 0 or more cardinality.

I cannot change the format of XML.

Comment: I haven't tried it using the XPathNavigator, but in XPath, a double forward slash `//` will return all matches - see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to worked for me:

```
        string schemaXPath = "//parent[@name='Iam']//toy[@name='wii']";
        XPathNavigator schemaNavigator  = oXmlDocument.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator nodeIter = schemaNavigator.Select(schemaXPath, namespaceMgr);

        while (nodeIter.MoveNext() == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nodeIter.Current.Name);
        }
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Cheers!